# .htaccess redirection goes to infinity loop

Tags: php, angularjs, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm using `Angular JS` and for `SEO` purpose i'm redirecting all crawl request to static html page content.

I'm using `Apache` server so in `.htaccess` file i have written :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} facebookexternalhit [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Twitterbot [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Baiduspider [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MetaURI [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} mediawords [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} FlipboardProxy [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=(.*?)\/*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ snapshots/$1.html [R=301,L]
```

But it goes to infinity redirection.

Please goto here : http://www.redirect-checker.org/index.php and enter link as :http://templatic.net/test/job_category/mobile and select search engine as `Googlebot` so it will redirect to like :

[image]

So please help me to stop this...

Answer (score 0):

Once any `RewriteCond` is matched, and the request `test/job_category/mobile` is rewritten to `test/snapshots/job_category/mobile.html`, the rewritten request is handed back to the URL parsing engine and the ruleset is run again from the start.

This time, it will again match the `HTTP_USER_AGENT` and be rewritten to `test/snapshots/snapshots/job_category/mobile.html.html`, and sent back again, and be rewritten again, etc...

The fix is to, in your RewriteRule, prevent rewriting if the request already starts with `snapshots/`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} facebookexternalhit [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Twitterbot [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Baiduspider [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MetaURI [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} mediawords [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} FlipboardProxy [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=(.*?)\/*$
RewriteRule ^(?!snapshots/)(.*)$ snapshots/$1.html [R=301,L]
```